# Is there a way to combine multiple EditingElementStyle properties into 1 DataGridTextColumn? XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm extremely new to WPF and pretty sure I don't have the right question in the subject line, anyway I'm trying to set a MaxLength to a DataGridTextColumn but when I do I'm told 'The property "EditingElementStyle" is set multiple times' I can see that in the second line of code I have EditingElementyStyle="{StaticResource TextboxToUpper}" but I'm wondering how I can add the MaxLength to that?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment"  Binding="{Binding Comment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" CellStyle=" 
{StaticResource EditableDataGridCell}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBoxToUpper}">

<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter  Property="MaxLength" Value="255"/>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`Style.BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment"  Binding="{Binding Comment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" CellStyle="{StaticResource EditableDataGridCell}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle >
       <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxToUpper}">
          <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="255"/>
       </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that states 'Cannot find the Style Property 'MaxLength' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' along with the error 

'The TypeConverter for "Style" does not support converting from a string'

Comment: `TargetType` must be "TextBox". Changed it.

Comment: Ok great got that fixed but I have one last error. 

It's coming from the first line that has 'CellStyle', the error is 'The TypeConverter "Style" does not support converting from a string'

Comment: Some space characters. Removed them.